# Magento 2 custom theme Integration

Tags: theme-fallback, luma-theme, parent-child-theme, integration

First I am new to magento development and theme integration. As reading forum  on the magento theme, created custom theme folder structure with listed file as below....

```
Magento\app\design\frontend\drEcom\tQCustometheme
```

- composer.json
- registration.php
- theme.xml
- /media
- /web

But can't got which and where the phtml files are located, so i can overwrite it???

Can someone please help/guide on this?

Comment: drEcom is my custom theme's <vendor name>. and theme name is <tQCustometheme>

Comment: have you got solution?

Comment: nope - i was stucked @ css and image not getting redered after appliing my custome theme from parent theme!!

Comment: have you set parent theme to your custom theme ?

Comment: yep - " <parent>Magento/Luma</parent>"

Comment: have your redeploy pub static?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50365/discussion-between-draval-and-chirag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`Magento\app\design\frontend\drEcom\tQCustometheme\{Default_Module}\templates\{yourovrride.phtml}`**.

let's say you have to override

**`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/details.phtml`**

file in your theme then your `details.phtml` file path should be like:

**`app\design\frontend\drEcom\tQCustometheme\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\details.phtml`**

Comment: Right now i am working for test/learn purpose only, so using the luma theme to override.

Comment: for luma theme, you can use this `app/design/frontend/Magento/luma` path

Comment: Let me try your suggestion... thanks for your efforts...